# Spark: How to use custom partitionner when writing data to Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, kafka-producer-api

When writing data to kafka, it is possible to use a column named key that will be used to choose the partition:

```
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
.write
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
.option("topic", "topic1")
.save()
```

I need to manually decide the partition, **independently from the key**. Is it possible to specify partition manually ? Or give a custom partitionner so that I control what is the logic that choose the partition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to add option `kafka.partitioner.class` with your custom partitioner with appropriate logic.

```scala
val dataStreamWriter: DataStreamWriter[Row] = ???
dataStreamWriter.option("kafka.partitioner.class", "com.example.CustomKafkaPartitioner")
```

Comment: can I do this in pyspark as well?